# To add a "green point" to an arrow

Tags: keynote

In Keynote, to add an arrow from, for example, one text box to another, we can use either

- a normal arrow
- or a connection line and then to make one of its heads to be an arrow

(the second and third shapes on my screenshot respectively).

Notice the connection line is automatically connected to any text box nearby, whereas normal arrow doesn't. And also notice connection line have a greed "dot" in its middle, which means you can freely adjust its curvature.

Okay, and now my question. How can I add this "green point" to a normal arrow? That's it.

[image]

Comment: So basically you want to convert a straight line into a bezier curve?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, probably. (But if you mean to select a normal arrow and then select "Make Editable" from its context menu, this is a solution that works differently, and not exactly what I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can. If you want to make a curved arrow, you can use the 'connection line' and add the arrow. When moving the ends of the line, hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> to prevent it from automatically connecting to another item.